# I cannot make my button to open the dropdown of the menu when I click the icon

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclicklistener

I have a  dropdown menu that need to be opened but nothing happens. Also, it appears that the function is undefined. I put the function in another jsx but nothing. It appears this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MyFunction'). Apparently, the function is declared and being used. I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
this is the code where the button with the onClick is so as to open the dropdown when I click the button:
```

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react' 
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { CounterContext, CartContext } from '../../context/AppContext'
import Dropdown from '../dropdown/Dropdown'
import Button from '../button/Button'

import './Nav.css'



const Header = () => {
    let count = useContext(CounterContext)
    let [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartContext)

    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow ">
                <Link to='/'><img className="logo ml-3" src='./images/g-shoe-new-logo.jpg' alt='logo' /></Link>
                <button onClick={this.MyFunction} className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="bi bi-menu-up"></span>
                </button>
                 <MyFunction/>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto pt-4 mr-2">
                        <Link to='/'>
                            <li className="nav-item active">
                                <p>Home</p>
                            </li>
                        </Link>

                        <Link to='/products'>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <p>Products</p>
                            </li>
                        </Link>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            {/* cart dropdown */}
                            <div className="dropdown m-0 p-0 dropleft">
                                <button className="btn m-0 p-0" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <div className="cart"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 2H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 4H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1.5 6A.5.5 0 0 1 13 11H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485-.379L1.61 3H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.14 5l1.25 5h8.22l1.25-5H3.14zM5 13a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zm9-1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0z"/>
</svg></div>
                                    <div className="counter">
                                        <p className='count'>{count[0]}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                                <div className="dropdown-menu mt-4" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <div className='items'>
                                        {
                                            cart.length ? (
                                                cart.map((item) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <Dropdown key={item.id} item={item} />
                                                    )
                                                })
                                            )
                                                :
                                                <p>Your cart is empty</p>
                                        }
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="dropdown-item bbtn-droopdown">
                                        <div className="moreProd">
                                            <Link to='/checkout'>
                                                <Button value='Go To CheckOut' />
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;

function MyFunction() {
    document.getElementById("navbarSupportedContent").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches(".navbar-toggler")) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse navbar-collapse");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is dropdown:

```
import React from 'react';

const Dropdown = ({ item }) => {
    const { name, imageUrl, price, quantity } = item;
    return (
        <div className="dropdown-item">
            <div className="image">
                <img src={imageUrl} alt='shoes'/>
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <span className='name'>{name}</span>
                <span className='price'>{quantity} X ${price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown;
```

I have two dropdowns to make but I started with the first one and have an error so I didn't use the function for the second dropdown. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You really should not have to have to use DOM methods in react to select and add class to elments.

Comment: Thanks! What you recommend instead of using Dom methods?